# repository for Node on a central server

Tags: javascript, node.js, maven

How to make Own repository for node package Manager to be used globally within an organisation to avoid security risks, just like we configure repo for maven

Comment: Google "private npm". Try top two or three hits. Or try private Git repos.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: https://github.com/rlidwka/sinopia

Sinopia is a private npm you can create.

I´ve used this module for private repositories and it´s very simple to install. You must configure each client to publish modules to this server. The docs will guide you.

Has support to docker.